# how to wrapping vue pwa with react native android webview

Tags: android, react-native, vue.js, webview, progressive-web-apps

i build a vue pwa
and i want wrapping it with react-native android webview.
this is react-native App.js code

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
render() {
    return (
        <WebView
            source={{uri: 'https://stackoverflow.com/' }} //good working
            // source={{uri: my vuejs pwa }} //not working
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            mixedContentMode={'compatibility'}
        />
    );
}
```

i dont know what to do T.T